# Grails support for new Maven Central

Tags: maven, grails

I was trying to pick up dependencies from the maven central repo and it looks like the URL to download the same has recently moved from repo1.maven.org to search.maven.org with a different format and as such Grails 2.2.2 isn't able to resolve it.

Do we know if this has been updated in the newer grails versions and if not is there a suggested elegant work around for this short of downloading the jars to the lib folder and renaming them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL hasn't changed, e.g. see http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/oauth/spring-security-oauth2/1.0.5.RELEASE/

What did change (months ago) is that their web-based search moved to search.maven.org. But if the URL changed or if you want another custom repo, you could easily add it to your BuildConfig.groovy using `mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"` substituting the correct URL

Note that `grailsCentral()` is a front-end for other repos, in addition to having a few jars there for real. Most of the resources there are passthroughs to Maven Central or other repos. It should be first in your repo list so it's accessed first, and then if something isn't there it can fall back to one of the other defined repos.

Comment: Thanks Burt. This worked. I could have sworn I tried the same thing earlier but it kept failing to resolve and hence my though was something changed the way they access the URL. But clearly that was a fail on my part :)